# How to fake an Image for dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, tdd

For class my team and I are required to create a project using Test Driven Development. We're having issues, however, with dependency injection. We understand the idea, making code unit testable by "faking" data from external sources, but some data types are giving is trouble. For example, we can't figure out how to "fake" an Image (java.awt.Image). What we really want is just an "empty" or "blank" image, but java always wants us to point it to a file.

Before injection, the test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testThatPieceInitializesWithValues() {
    Image img = null;
    try {
        //Don't have piece images yet...using board as placeholder
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/board.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    Piece p = new Piece(PieceType.Camel, img);
    assertNotNull(p);
    assertEquals(PieceType.Camel, p.getType());
    assertEquals(img, p.getImage());
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I havn't been able to find anything worthwhile on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). They extend Image and can be created in arbitrary sizes and bit depths. You can even [draw on them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics()) if it matters for your test.

```
Image image = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```